# Using a for loop to generate elements of a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I am trying to compute with the equation [image]

and I would like to store each value into a row vector. Here is my attempt:

```
multiA = [1];
multiB = [];
NA = 6;
NB = 4;
q = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]; 


for i=2:7
  multiA = [multiA(i-1), (factorial(q(i) + NA - 1))/(factorial(q(i))*factorial(NA-1))];
  %multiA = [multiA, multiA(i)];
end

multiA
```

But this does not work. I get the error message

```
Attempted to access multiA(3); index out
of bounds because numel(multiA)=2.

  multiA = [multiA(i-1), (factorial(q(i)
  + NA -
  1))/(factorial(q(i))*factorial(NA-1))];
```

Is my code even remotely close to what I want to achieve? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Answer given below is correct and the recommended method, but understand your mistake here. When you do, `multiA = [multiA(i-1),<<big_expression>>`], then, at each iteration, you just get 2-element long vector `multiA` since `mutliA(i-1)` and your `<<big_expression>>` are both scalars. If you wanted to follow your approach, you should have done-> `multiA = [multiA,<<big_expression>>]` and declare `multiA=[]` prior to entering `for` loop. This is what MATLAB is telling you, `numel(multiA)=2`.

Comment: +1 for `meshgrid` use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need any loop, just use the vector directly.

```
NA = 6;
q = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]; 

multiA = factorial(q + NA - 1)./(factorial(q).*factorial(NA-1))
```

gives

```
multiA =

     1     6    21    56   126   252   462
```

---

For multiple `N` a loop isn't necessary neither:

```
N = [6,8,10];
q = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]; 
[N,q] = meshgrid(N,q)
multiA = factorial(q + N - 1)./(factorial(q).*factorial(N-1))
```

---

Also consider the following remarks regarding the overflow for `n > 21` in:

```
f = factorial(n)
```

> **Limitations**
>
> *The result is only accurate for double-precision values of n that are less than or equal to 21. A larger value of n produces a result that
>   has the correct order of magnitude and is accurate for the first 15
>   digits. This is because double-precision numbers are only accurate up
>   to 15 digits.*
>   *For single-precision input, the result is only accurate for values of n that are less than or equal to 13. A larger value of n produces a
>   result that has the correct order of magnitude and is accurate for the
>   first 8 digits. This is because single-precision numbers are only
>   accurate up to 8 digits.*

Comment: Clearly I was over-thinking this. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 5):

Factorials of moderately large numbers can cause **overflow**. Two possible approaches to prevent that:

1. Avoid computing terms that will cancel. This approach is specially suited to the case when `q` is of the form 1,2,... as in your example. It also has the advantage that, for each  value of `q`, the result for the previous value is reutilized, thus minimizing the number of operations:

   ```
   >> q = 1:6;
   >> multiA = cumprod((q+NA-1)./q)
   multiA =
        6    21    56   126   252   462
   ```

   Note that `0` is not allowed in `q`. But the result for `0` is just `1`, so the final result would be just `[1 multiA]`.
2. For `q` arbitrary (not necessarily of the form 1,2,...), you can use the [`gammaln`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/gammaln.html) function, which gives the *logarithms* of the factorials:

   ```
   >> q = [0 1 2 6 3];
   >> multiA = exp(gammaln(q+NA)-gammaln(q+1)-gammaln(NA));
   >>multiA =
          1.0000    6.0000   21.0000  462.0000   56.0000
   ```

Comment: @thewaywewalk :-) One rarely has the chance to wield the logarithmic gamma function meaningfully

Answer (score 1):

You want to append a new element to the end of 'multiA':

```
for i=2:7
  multiA = [multiA, (factorial(q(i) + NA - 1))/(factorial(q(i))*factorial(NA-1))];
end
```

A function handle makes it much simpler:

```
%define:
omega=@(q,N)(factorial(q + N - 1))./(factorial(q).*factorial(N-1))
%use:
omega(0:6,4) %q=0..6, N=4
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to use `nchoosek` as opposed to `factorial`. The latter can overflow quite easily, I'd imagine.

```
multiA=nan(1,7);

for i=1:7

  multiA(i)=nchoosek(q(i)+N-1, q(i));

end
```